# Hide Text or Lock Specific ListView Column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need to know if it's possible or not, and if possible can someone help me?

I want to hide because when I check my `lisview checkbox` I'm telling  my program add `1` if `checked` and `0` if `unchecked` and I need these numbers so I can't just remove the column.

In this picture you can see what I'm talking about:

[image]

Can someone help me with this? because I don't want the user see the numbers.

I also found this in StackOverflow:

```
private void listView_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    e.NewWidth = listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
}
```

But that code will lock all the columns can someone make a work arround and do it just for the 1st column? becuse I can change the width the numbers will get hided but I need the other columns resizable.

Comment: You can make the text transparent, eg :`listView1.Items[1].SubItems[1].ForeColor = Color.Transparent;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to lock the first column, just add a check on columnIndex :

```
private void listView_ColumnWidthChanging(object sender, ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs e)
{
    **if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)**
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        e.NewWidth = listView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! That woked now i will just resize the collumn and no one will see the text on it